# Python cannot work as dbus server and client in the multi-thread enviroment

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created the dbus server as the following code, named it as server1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import dbus.service
import dbus.glib
import glib
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop


class APP_Server(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self):
        bus = dbus.SessionBus(private = True, mainloop = DBusGMainLoop())
        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName('de.test.app1', bus)
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, '/de/test/app1_obj_path')

    @dbus.service.method("test.app1.interface",)
    def is_ready(self):           
        return True

def publish_dbus():
    loop = glib.MainLoop()
    APP_Server()
    loop.run()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    gobject.threads_init()
    dbus.glib.init_threads()
    publish_dbus()
```

And then I want to access dbus service in the server1.py by the following code, named it as server2.py which also will work as a dbus server.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import dbus.service
import dbus.glib
import glib
import dbus.mainloop
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


class APP_Server(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self):
        bus = dbus.SessionBus(private = True, mainloop = DBusGMainLoop())
        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName('de.test.app3', bus)
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, '/de/test/app3_obj_path')

    @dbus.service.method("test.app3.interface",)
    def is_ready(self):           
        return True

def call_dbus():
    bus_name = 'de.test.app1'
    obj_path = '/de/test/app1_obj_path'
    interface_name = 'test.app1.interface'
    count = 1
    while count < 1000:
        proxy_bus = dbus.SessionBus(private = True)
        obj = None
        try:
            obj = proxy_bus.get_object(bus_name, obj_path)
        except:
            sleep(1)
            obj = proxy_bus.get_object(bus_name, obj_path)
        ready = obj.get_dbus_method('is_ready', interface_name)
        ready(pid_, bin_path)
        count += 1
        print count 

def publish_dbus():
    loop = glib.MainLoop()
    APP_Server()
    loop.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gobject.threads_init()
    dbus.glib.init_threads()
    th1 = Thread(target = publish_dbus)
    th1.start()
    th2 = Thread(target = call_dbus)
    th2.start()
    sleep(10000000)
```

Then after run the server2.py, the application will terminated without finished all the dbus call in the thread "call_dbus".

And  if I tried with the follwoing code, only changed the code in server2.py as the following:

FROM:

```
 proxy_bus = dbus.SessionBus(private = True)
```

TO:

```
  proxy_bus = dbus.SessionBus(private = True, mainloop = dbus.mainloop.NULL_MAIN_LOOP)
```

Now, there will have many connnections after the thread "callbus" finished by using the tools "d-feet" which can be used as a d-bus debugger to check if the dbus server is ready or  if the dbus connection has been established.

If someone can make some suggeston to make it work normally??

Answer (score 2):

What i've noticed is this:

- Your bus/object names don't match.
- You create a new dbus connection each time in your while loop. Very bad idea, specially seen that you don't close them.
  Either move the call out of the loop, or use a shared connection (`private=False`)
- You don't really need an own thread to publish the dbus object, that's what the mainloop is for anyway.
- If you run a mainloop in a different thread, make sure you have a way to stop, otherwise `kill` will be the only way of terminating your program. Or put int in your main thread, then it should at least react to <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>
- The sleep at the end of your program is unnecessary. As long as there are running non-daemon threads around the program won't exit anyway.

Putting all this together, this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import dbus.service
import dbus.glib
import glib
import dbus.mainloop
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


class APP_Server(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self):
        bus = dbus.SessionBus(private = True, mainloop = DBusGMainLoop())
        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName('de.test.app3', bus)
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, '/de/test/app3_obj_path')

    @dbus.service.method("test.app3.interface",)
    def is_ready(self):           
        return True

def call_dbus():
    bus_name = 'de.test.app3'
    obj_path = '/de/test/app3_obj_path'
    interface_name = 'test.app3.interface'
    proxy_bus = dbus.SessionBus(private = True)
    count = 1
    while count < 1000:
        obj = None
        try:
            obj = proxy_bus.get_object(bus_name, obj_path)
        except:
            sleep(1)
            obj = proxy_bus.get_object(bus_name, obj_path)
        ready = obj.get_dbus_method('is_ready', interface_name)
        #ready(pid_, bin_path)
        count += 1
        print count 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gobject.threads_init()
    dbus.glib.init_threads()
    loop = glib.MainLoop()
    server = APP_Server()
    #th1 = Thread(target = publish_dbus)
    #th1.start()
    th2 = Thread(target = call_dbus)
    th2.start()
    loop.run()
```